# Почему НЕ пишется раздельно в выражении "не ровён час"?

Tags: частица-не, cслитно-раздельно

В написании НЕ наблюдались колебания. Например, у Даля: "неровен час — всяко бывает". Почему сейчас утвердилось именно отрицание с раздельным написание НЕ? И почему ударение падает на Ё, это народно-просторечный стиль?

Answer (score 1):

В разных словарях по-разному:

> Не ровен (неровён) час (см. Ровный). ([Большой толковый словарь](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D1%87%D0%B0%D1%81&all=x))
>
> НЕРОВЕН; НЕРОВЁН. ◊ Неровен (неровён) час, в зн. вводн. сл. Разг. А вдруг (при ожидании чего-л. неприятного, опасаясь чего-л.). Н. час, опоздаем на поезд. ([Большой толковый словарь](http://m.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%91%D0%BD))
>
> Не ровён час ([Толковый словарь Ожегова](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ogegova/121850))

Частотность в Нацкорпусе (слитно — раздельно) 193:288.

Comment: Да, я тоже говорила о колебаниях. Но в современных источниках указано раздельное написание. Ответ Грамоты.ру на вопрос 201716: В большинстве доступных нам словарей (в том числе «Русском орфографическом словаре» РАН) фиксируется раздельное написание _не ровён час_. Также: http://hobby-day.3dn.ru/publ/4-1-0-35, также: http://orf.textologia.ru/definit/ne-roven-chas/?n=73491&q=532  И главное - как объяснить выбор написания?